# Jenkins - Manual Deployment From Git using Build Number

Tags: git, jenkins

I was able to integrate Git with jenkins and created the Build pipeline as soon as any push to Git occurred.

I was unable to find a way to do a manual deployment of Git build just by passing build number as the parameter.

For Example:-

1. I am pushing some changes to Git and my build job automatically triggers and it creates the build with the number #101.
2. Now I want to manually deploy this build to server by passing the build number #101.

Any suggestion or help is appreciated!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is to upload your artifact to something like Artefactory after all your automated test cases have passed as part of a "build" job.

You should create a second "Deploy" job to download your archived artifact and deploy it to a target environment via a parameter to the deploy job.

Comment: Andrew. Thank you for your response. I appreciate it. But that's not what i was looking for.. I found a way to checkout the particular git build using jenkins API by passing build number as the parameter. sample script...
    `J = Jenkins(url, username, password)

     job = J[jobName]

    lgb = job.get_last_good_build()

    job = J.get_job(jobName)

    build = job.get_build(buildNumber)

    return build.get_revision()`